# Concatenar variável com id buscada por Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Olá!

Tenho um código para autocomplete aqui que está me dando um pouco de dor de cabeça.

Meu código consiste em um foreach que gera uma linha a cada registro encontrado, a cada linha gera um botão que chama um modal, coloquei na linha que chama o modal uma variável que vai se iterando e concatenei essa variável com a id do modal, assim pude ligar o modal a linha correta.

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAdicao<?php echo htmlspecialchars($idModal); ?>" class="botao btn-editar">Editar</button>
```

Logo quando a variável se refere a linha das 08:00, o modal abre com possibilidade de edição daquela linha, até aí tudo ok.

Meu problema é que o Javascript do autocomplete busca por uma id de input chamada #busca, porém só funciona na primeira ocorrência do modal, isso porque na segunda o #busca já foi utilizado, preciso então que a id desse input mude acompanhando o modal, logo pensei no seguinte:

```
<input type="text" id="busca<?php echo htmlspecialchars($idModal); ?>" placeholder="Identidade" name="rgPaciente" class="mx-sm-69 form-control" required>
```

A lógica é simples, já fiz isso em código pequeno, mas não soube aplicar no autocomplete pois sou bem leigo e não compreendo bem o código por completo ainda.

Amostra do código:

```
$(function() {

    // Atribui evento e função para limpeza dos campos
    $('#busca').on('input', limpaCampos);

    // Dispara o Autocomplete a partir do segundo caracter
    $( "#busca" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "include/procura_paciente.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    acao: 'autocomplete',
                    parametro: $('#busca').val()
                },
                success: function(data) {
                   response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#busca").val( ui.item.rg );
            carregarDados();
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#busca").val( ui.item.rg );
            return false;
        }
    })
    .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<br><b>Paciente: </b>" + item.nome + " - <b> RG: </b>" + item.rg + "</a><br>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };

    // Função para carregar os dados da consulta nos respectivos campos
    function carregarDados(){
        var busca = $('#busca').val();

        if(busca != "" && busca.length >= 2){
            $.ajax({
                url: "include/procura_paciente.php",
                dataType: "json",   
                data: {
                    acao: 'consulta',
                    parametro: $('#busca').val()
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                   $('#nomePaciente').val(data[0].nome);
                   $('#nomePaciente2').val(data[0].nome);
                   $('#rgPaciente').val(data[0].rg);
                   $('#nascimentoPaciente').val(data[0].nascimento);
                   $('#cpfPaciente').val(data[0].cpf);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Função para limpar os campos caso a busca esteja vazia
    function limpaCampos(){
       var busca = $('#busca').val();

       if(busca == ""){
       $('#nomePaciente').val('');
           $('#nomePaciente2').val('');
           $('#rgPaciente').val('')
           $('#nascimentoPaciente').val('')
           $('#cpfPaciente').val('')
       }
    }
});
```

Primeira linha que chama o modal:

```
<td>08:00 ID DA LINHA: 0</td>
<td><button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAdicao0" class="botao btn-editar">Editar</button></td>
```

Abaixo algumas amostras do código já com PHP renderizado:
Primeiro modal:

```
<!-- Início do Modal de Adição de Agendamento-->
<div id="modalAdicao0" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade text-left">
  <div role="document" class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 id="exampleModalLabel" class="modal-title">Novo Agendamento para João Santos</h4>
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" class="close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Preencha os campos abaixo 08:00 ID 0</p>
        <form id="novoAgendamento" method="POST" action="include/novo_agendamento.php">
          <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="busca" class="sr-only">Identidade</label>
              <input type="text" id="busca" placeholder="Identidade" name="rgPaciente" class="mx-sm-69 form-control procura" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="nascimentoPaciente" class="sr-only">Nascimento</label>
              <input type="text" id="nascimentoPaciente" placeholder="Nascimento" name="nascimentoPaciente" class="mx-sm-69 form-control nascimentoPaciente" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nomePaciente"></label>
            <input type="hidden" id="nomePaciente" name="nomePaciente" class="form-control nomePaciente">
            <input type="hidden" id="cpfPaciente" name="cpfPaciente" class="form-control cpfPaciente">
            <input type="hidden" id="horaPaciente" name="horaPaciente" value="08:00" class="form-control horaPaciente">
            <input type="hidden" id="dataPaciente" name="dataPaciente" value="2018-05-19" class="form-control dataPaciente">
            <input type="hidden" id="medicoPaciente" name="medicoPaciente" value="João Santos" class="form-control medicoPaciente">
            <input type="text" id="nomePaciente2" placeholder="Nome do Paciente" class="form-control nomePaciente2" disabled="">     
            <label for="observacaoPaciente"></label>
            <input type="text" name="observacaoPaciente" placeholder="Observação" class="form-control observacaoPaciente" required>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary">Fechar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agendar</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>                                      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Fim do Modal de Adição de Agendamento-->
```

Segunda linha que chama o modal:

```
<td>09:00 ID DA LINHA: 1</td>
<td><button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAdicao1" class="botao btn-editar">Editar</button></td>
```

Segundo modal:

```
    <!-- Início do Modal de Adição de Agendamento-->
<div id="modalAdicao1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade text-left">
  <div role="document" class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 id="exampleModalLabel" class="modal-title">Novo Agendamento para João Santos</h4>
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" class="close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Preencha os campos abaixo 09:00 ID 1</p>
        <form id="novoAgendamento" method="POST" action="include/novo_agendamento.php">
          <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="busca" class="sr-only">Identidade</label>
              <input type="text" id="busca" placeholder="Identidade" name="rgPaciente" class="mx-sm-69 form-control procura" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="nascimentoPaciente" class="sr-only">Nascimento</label>
              <input type="text" id="nascimentoPaciente" placeholder="Nascimento" name="nascimentoPaciente" class="mx-sm-69 form-control nascimentoPaciente" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nomePaciente"></label>
            <input type="hidden" id="nomePaciente" name="nomePaciente" class="form-control nomePaciente">
            <input type="hidden" id="cpfPaciente" name="cpfPaciente" class="form-control cpfPaciente">
            <input type="hidden" id="horaPaciente" name="horaPaciente" value="09:00" class="form-control horaPaciente">
            <input type="hidden" id="dataPaciente" name="dataPaciente" value="2018-05-19" class="form-control dataPaciente">
            <input type="hidden" id="medicoPaciente" name="medicoPaciente" value="João Santos" class="form-control medicoPaciente">
            <input type="text" id="nomePaciente2" placeholder="Nome do Paciente" class="form-control nomePaciente2" disabled="">     
            <label for="observacaoPaciente"></label>
            <input type="text" name="observacaoPaciente" placeholder="Observação" class="form-control observacaoPaciente" required>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary">Fechar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agendar</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>                                      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Fim do Modal de Adição de Agendamento-->
```

Comment: Olá amigo! Seria bem melhor vc colocar o código já renderizado pelo PHP, o HTML puro para que possamos analisar a até tentar reproduzir.  Colocando códigos PHP e consulta de banco de dados torna a análise 1000x mais complicada pq não tem como a gente reproduzir. Coloca a parte do HTML renderizado e o JavaScript que já ajuda muito, assim a gente pode ver as `id`s e os valores já retornados do PHP de forma clara, podendo ver onde que está o problema e os conflitos.

Comment: Fiz uma edição, espero que ajude.

Comment: Fernando, obg por editar a pergunta, mas eu acho que ela ainda está mt grande e pouco clara. Acho que em 5 linhas de texto vc consegue explicar o que quer fazer. O que vc quer fazer? Tente sintetizar o que vc quer fazer e o que não está dando certo.

Answer (score 1):

Quando fazemos referência a um objeto no documento pelo seu identificador (ID). Esperamos obter um único resultado. Isso porque o id serve justamente para isso. Ser único. Sua ideia:

```
<input type="text" id="busca<?php echo htmlspecialchars($idModal); ?>" placeholder="Identidade" name="rgPaciente" class="mx-sm-69 form-control" required>
```

Me parece ser razoável pois vincula a busca a um id especifico. 
Porém no seu script ajax estas a capturar um único id enquanto existem vários.

Logo agora sua ideia de razoável passou a ser um grande fiasco. Isso por que agora vamos ter que nos preocupar em relacionar esses ids ao seletor na função ajax. Uma solução mais simples consiste em selecionar os valores através do uso de classes passando o id do campo busca para ser utilizada no retorno dos dados. Isto é ! Para sabermos onde colocar o resultado da busca. Ex. `$('#nome-'+id)`:

```js
 $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.busca').change(function(){
            busca(this.value , this.id);
        })

        function busca(busca , id){
            // Busca
            let resultado =  'resultato para a busca ' + busca;
            //Retornando os resultados
            $('#nome-'+id).val(resultado);
        }
        
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <input id="1" class="busca" type="text">Busca
    <input id="nome-1" type="text">Resultado
    </form>
    <form action="">
        <input id="2" class="busca" type="text">Busca
        <input id="nome-2" type="text">Resultado
    </form>
    <form action="">
        <input id="3" class="busca" type="text">Busca
        <input id="nome-3" type="text">Resultado
    </form>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Eu estudei mais cedo sobre identificar por classe, mas esbarrei no mesmo problema, como ficará o javascript após isso, atribuindo um nome de classe teste para cada input e mudando de #teste para .teste lá no arquivo do js terminou por funcionar da mesma forma que identificando pela id, a dificuldade de executar nas próximas ocorrências do modal persistiu, tô tentando entender agora tua dica pra tentar aplicar aqui, o que não tá fácil haha.

Answer (score 0):

Lamento ter que dizer isso mas essa sua aplicação está mal estruturada e devido a isso, até mesmo respondendo a dúvida, você terá outros problemas que não terá como resolver. Costumo dizer que quando a pergunta é complexa demais, não estamos fazendo a coisa certa.

1. Procure centralizar e/ou reaproveitar as coisas, como por exemplo, tenha apenas uma Modal.
2. Na modal você está usando o ID BUSCA no campo do RG, IDs não podem se repetir, crie um ID único para cada elemento
3. Use a callback select do autocomplete para chamar carregaDados(item.id) com p ID do paciente, a partir dele você obtem todo o resto
4. No seu botão de abrir a modal use onclick="carregaHorario('09:00')" e crie essa função para receber o horário e colocar o valor no campo na modal

Espero ter ajudado!

Boa sorte!